# Python IDLE how do I get from editor to shell

Tags: python, python-idle

If I'm in the Python IDLE editor and the shell is not open, is there some way to open the shell without running a program? I expect it's something simple that I just can't find.
Thanks

Comment: How are you in the IDLE editor without the shell?  Are you using another editor?

Comment: Open your system's command prompt, and type `python`?

Comment: You type python in CMD and it's not shown up?

Comment: You can run the currently selected program by pressing `F5`. That will bring up a "console" window and run the program. Once it's done, it will return to a python interpeter.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3.8 its just `Run -> Python Shell` if I am understanding your question correctly

[image: python shell image]

Answer (score 2):

For windows:

- `Win+R` to open `run` window
- `cmd` to open, well, the command line
- `python` to run python. Make sure you've added the `python.exe` file to PATH